# Jenkins Auto Reload Configuration Possible?

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins servers with sharing one jobs directory to make high availability.
However if one server built any of the workspace, another server will fail to built it, because they store next available built number in the memory.

So I need a plugin that can auto reload job's configuration periodically. Does anyone know about a suitable plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this kind of plugin exists or not. But to reload job's configuration periodically, you can use a programmatically way by combining with the `crontab` utility.

Step 1:

Write a Groovy script `reload-config` to do the reload configuration.

Step 2:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins_url/ groovy reload-config.groovy
```

Step 3:

Setup an `crontab` task to execute Step 2.

Comment: Great, thanks! This can solve my problem alternatively. Plus, I've found the reload-config script from: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216552/does-anyone-know-how-to-reload-hudson-configuration-without-restarting[link]