# Jenkins load system environment variable from system ( Windows )

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I have a simple Jenkins job  ( Jenkins 1.514  ) and I’m looking for a way that every time job is running it will refresh a specific system environment variable.
The variable is set by a different software so I don’t want to set it in the job itself I just want to reload it, I also don't want to stop Jenkins slave and start it again.
Any ideas ?

Comment: is it a windows server? is it a development machine? For real environments , linux is the best alternative. In linux environment environment vars could be setted in a simple file and jenkins could be edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You can reload the system configuration in Jenkins by following the given path:

***Jenkins Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Reload Configuration from Disk***

It will load all the changes you have done on your machine.

For automatically uploading add below in your job and run your job:-

curl http://[jenkins-server]/reload

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to run automatically every time I run the job.

Comment: I ran call "C:\Program Files\curl-7.64.1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe" http://<SERVER>:8080/reload, but still windows env variable were not refreshed

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216552/how-to-reload-hudson-configuration-without-restarting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521689/jenkins-auto-reload-configuration-possible