# How to configure JaCoCo Jenkins plugin through Shell or API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

Is there a way to configure the [JaCoCo Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jacoco) coverage threshold through a shell script or API? For ex: I want to make an app to change code coverage threshold values for my Jenkins Jobs. How would I do it if I want my Jenkins instance abstracted?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out its a bit simple really. Plugin configurations are stored in an XML file. Global configurations in `.jenkins` root folder and job specific configurations in `$HOME/.jenkins/jobs/{JOB_NAME}/config.xml`.

Modify the `config.xml` file to store new configurations. This configuration file is exposed by each job at `http://<SERVER>:<PORT>/jenkins/job/<JOB NAME>/config.xml`. Since Jenkins loads this data at first load, you need to execute 'Reload Configuration From Disk' in Global configuration.

Since we're updating the XML from an API, you need to tell jenkins to reload configuration from an API as well. To do that, execute a shell to use `jenkins_cli.jar`'s `reload-configuration` command.

Reference : [Does anyone know how to reload hudson configuration without restarting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216552/does-anyone-know-how-to-reload-hudson-configuration-without-restarting)