# Partial Job Reload From Disk Without Reloading the Entire Server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Recently someone deleted a folder from our Jenkins instance. We were able to recover the jobs from a recent backup and apply them back into the jenkins_home folder on the server. The only way we knew to reload those jobs from disk was to hit the button "Reload Configuration from Disk"  (Jenkins->Manage Jenkins). As our server has thousands of jobs and the performance is not...er...enough it took over 10 hours to reload the entire folder and job configuration from disk.

Today, I found an answer in a simple groovy script from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216552/does-anyone-know-how-to-reload-hudson-configuration-without-restarting/) that talked about loading a single job [see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077362/1930544) from disk. Thanks [Andreas Panagiotidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823368/andreas-panagiotidis)! With a little modification you can load all jobs that contain a string ("somestring"):

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource

def hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance;

for(job in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items) {   

    if (job.name.toLowerCase().contains("somestring")) {

        def configXMLFile = job.getConfigFile();
        def file = configXMLFile.getFile();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        job.updateByXml(new StreamSource(is));
        job.save();         
    }      
}
```

This took only seconds to run and all jobs in that folder were recovered.