# Jenkins - Job A sets the build number for Job B without reloading project configuration from disk

Tags: jenkins

I want to have one Jenkins job control the build number of another job but without the inconvenience of reloading the entire project configuration from disk. I have seen that it's easily possible to directly update the nextBuildNumber file of the target job (I can do this as a build step of Job A) but this does not take effect immediately. Restarting Jenkins or even reloading the Jenkins configs from disk takes way too long and can only be done when there are no builds in progress.

I have tried the groovy script mentioned in the below post by running it from the Manage Jenkins > Script Console. The same post also suggests the script can be saved as a file and run from the CLI. Can it be run from a build step?

I want Job A to determine Job B's next build number and set it so that Job B can run (later in the same day) with the desired build number.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077362/4306857

Perhaps I should clarify. I'm not familiar with Groovy so I'm looking at the various build step options like "Execute Windows batch command" which I have a lot of experience with. I can see an "Invoke Gradle script" option so I was wondering if there may be a plugin that can run Groovy scripts perhaps?

The reason this requirement has arisen is that we are compiling a product for two different platforms. We want to compile the codebase almost simultaneously for both platforms with two jobs (A & B) which will both update the JIRA cases included in the builds. We feel it will be less confusing to have both these jobs running with the same build number so that when we talk about a particular issue being addressed in build #75, say, we won't have to qualify that by stating the full job name. If JOB-A build #75 and JOB-B build #75 are both compiled on the same day from the same codebase we can test and compare the results of both builds with far less confusion than if the build numbers go out of sync.

Obviously, in the short term we will use the Set Next Build Number plugin to manually keep the build numbers in step but we want to automate this if possible.

Comment: I would change the script to use the readFile and writeFile steps instead of Java streams but otherwise it should work in a pipeline (which then can be triggered from the cli). I am curious, why you are needing this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, smelm. I have put some more context into the post.

Comment: Did you have a look at parallel build steps? That would be a lot easier than setting the build number of a job (since that one should be just incrementing normally)

Comment: Also, jenkins pipelines (especially scripted ones) are just groovy scripts. Jenkins provides some functions and it has some limitiation (in favor of restartability) but in the end it is just groovy

Comment: Thank you again, smelm. We're not using pipelines in our production system. The suggestions I've received already have given me some food for thought. I need to set aside a bit of time to try some out on my test Jenkins instance. I'll report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether or not you are using [Version Number plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/versionnumber/):

> ```
> [ X ] Create a formatted version number
> Build Display Name [ X ] Use the formatted version number for build display name.
> ```

Assuming you are NOT, this [groovy script](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216114978-How-to-set-next-build-number-in-Pipeline-job-) will do:

```
def NextNumber=42
job=Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('path/to/jobName')
job.nextBuildNumber = NextNumber
job.save();
```

You will  need [groovy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/) for that. Place that in an "Execute **system** Groovy script" step.  Make sure to choose **system groovy**. That will execute on the master, where the job config and metadata is stored so you have access to the Jenkins internals and data.

I'd suggest you should really be using the above options rather than relying on "keeping both jobs in sync" via a script or manually. You can then pass the label to be used from the first job as a parameter to the second job. That would also require [Parameterized Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/) as well as [Version Number](https://plugins.jenkins.io/versionnumber/) plugins.

You can even use `${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED}` or `${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}`, etc.

Postdate: thinking about the problemspace from a different perspective, that of running 2+ builds on different platforms (simultaneously), there's a plugin for that: [Matrix project](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-project/). You can run it as a freeatyle job on multiple nodes or is excellently described as [Matrix building in scripted pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/12/02/matrix-building-with-scripted-pipeline/). Not sure how that would tie in to JIRA.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not using the Version Number plugin. I am reasonably happy with the groovy script I read from the linked post. I'd be happy to try the groovy code snippet that you've suggested but can I run it as part of a build step somehow? Perhaps I'll have to research this separately.

Comment: Thanks for your updated detailed suggestion, Ian. We don't use pipeline in our production system so I will try this out on a test instance.

Comment: Added another option. How about a +1 until you evaluate?

Comment: I need to work on my reputation! As my "score" is below 15, my +1 is not publicly available, apparently. I do appreciate your interest and feedback on this.

Comment: Excellent answer, Ian. Thank you so much. As you suggested I installed the Groovy plugin and placed the groovy code in an "Execute system Groovy script" step of JOB_A: 
Prior to this is an Execute Windows batch command step:
echo %BUILD_NUMBER% > C:\Users\davidb\.jenkins\jobs\JOB_B\nextBuildNumber
And after it I have a Build other projects Action to run JOB_B.
The result is that so long as the build number of Job_A is initially higher the next build number of JOB_B, JOB_A will run followed by JOB_B and both jobs will have the same build number.

Comment: I think you have a fragile, rudimentary "that works", so, good on you. But I'd encourage looking at the other options mentioned as being more robust..

Comment: I agree, Ian. I have started to look at the Matrix solution and it has certainly piqued my interest. I have the plugin installed on my test Jenkins instance and need to find some quiet time to have a play. At least in the short term I have something that works for me to get me started. Thanks again for your help.