# How to remove old builds in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I removed old build folders from the build directory in Jenkins expecting them to be removed in the UI, unfortunately whilse these build directories are gone, their UI link still exists. I now have two questions:

1. How can I get rid of the defunct links in the UI?
2. How can I delete old build from cli and have it reflected in the UI?

Comment: As of Jenkins 1.626 this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13052966/107301 works

Comment: In Jenkins 2+ (mine is 2.89) in the Config of every Job there is now an option "Discard Old Builds" where you can specify if you want to delete builds older than X days and/or only keep X latest builds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must either restart Jenkins or reload the data, in order to reconcile the UI with its back end. There is no other way.

If you have access to the "Manage Jenkins" menu there is a link to "Reload Configuration from Disk", which is a little less invasive than a restart.

Keep in mind that the system will be not usable for a few seconds while the data is reloaded, just like during a full restart. If you have a lot of builds, this might take a little. So, make sure that this is ok with the other users of your system.

Answer (score 12):

A better way to remove old builds is [discard-old-build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) where you can specify how many builds you want to keep and all older builds are discarded.

Comment: Thanks. I will install that but I still need to get rid of the current mess.

Comment: Yes after the plugin is installed, set the number of builds you want to keep and run a fresh build. It will then cleanup all the older builds from the UI.

Comment: This answer does not resolve the original issue. As pointed out by Dark Star1  in the comment above the question was how to reconcile the deleted builds on the file system with what Jenkins displays. The discard-old-builds plugin can be used proactively to establish policies to decide how many builds to keep in the future, but will not refresh the web application.

Comment: Make sure to read the comments on the plugin page. Lots of people seem to have issues with missing / lost data.

Comment: Or [build history manager](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-history-manager-plugin) plugin