# How to manage the Jenkins old build history

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

as per the document https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin my jenkins has this plugin and defined days to keep buils as 60 but I observe there are old builds more than 60 days are available in the history.

what is the best way to to manage the old build? I am using Jenkins version 1.642.4.

Answer (score 2):

The question of cleaning builds has been answered extensively in various forms:

https://superuser.com/questions/589528/how-do-i-delete-the-builds-11-to-1717-in-jenkins

[How to remove old builds in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570179/how-to-remove-old-builds-in-jenkins)

[Jenkins delete builds older than latest 20 builds for all jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610053/jenkins-delete-builds-older-than-latest-20-builds-for-all-jobs)

[How do I clear my Jenkins/Hudson build history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410141/how-do-i-clear-my-jenkins-hudson-build-history)

As suggested in the last response, merely adding the plugin is not enough. You most likely need a system restart or possibly a new run of the job itself: that should clean up the history. Thst is for the built-in capability. You have referenced a post-build task step, which means the job MUST be run. You can search S/O for groovy scripts to rerun all jobs.

ps: you should probably consider u/g to 2.x; much better.