# Is there a way to define "number of builds" for JUnit test results in Jenkins?

Tags: xml, junit, jenkins, report

I am learning Jenkins. I just configured it to publish JUnit test results. Now it keeps accumulating all previous results in the plot. Please refer to the attached screen, which contains 20+ builds.

I am wondering whether I can configure it to only display last 10 builds?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Do you just want to restrict the number of builds in the graph?  or the number of builds in your build history?

Comment: to dkatzel, I just figured it out how to clean up the old history: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410141/how-do-i-clear-my-hudson-build-history. But I don't how to restrict the number of builds in the graph. Would you please show me how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out two ways to handle this issue by removing old build history.

1) Refer to answers to this thread: [How do I clear my Jenkins/Hudson build history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410141/how-do-i-clear-my-hudson-build-history)

2) In config page, you can set number of builds & artifacts you want to keep. Please refer to the screen shot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the number of builds shown for the built in test result trend graph.

If you have other plug-ins that have trend graphs you can see most of them have a link under the graph to "Configure" it which you can set the number of builds to use etc, but I don't see one for the test graph so I think you are stuck using the number of builds in your build history.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around which we found to be an acceptable solution:

You can install [Dashboard View plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View).

Follow these steps:

- create a new view of type `Dashboard`
- select the job(s) of which you want to display the `test result chart`
- click on the button `Add Dashboard Portlet to the top of the view`
- choose `Test Trend Chart`
- configure the desired `Number of (latest) days to display`
- save the view

On the newly created/configured view you now have a test results charts with your desired number of builds.