# Jenkins does not work correctly after system date was changed

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

To test something on Jenkins I changed the date to 3 days in the future. After I did the testing I set the date back to today but it seems that this causes some troubles.

Automated builds were running while I was testing so Jenkins already generated some builds/logs in the future. I think this might be causing problems now. When running a new build the green balls aren't flashing anymore and it looks like it is building but I don't see any console outputs in the logs on today.

Anyone also experienced this problem? How can I solve this? Maybe the deleting the logs in the future could help I think but how do you do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting the build history of all my jobs. %HUDSON_HOME%\jobs\ directory and delete all the subdirectories (only the directories, not config.xml!!) there as described in [How do I clear my Jenkins/Hudson build history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410141/how-do-i-clear-my-hudson-build-history) .